# Temporary method within method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, design-patterns, delegates, func

In the method below, there are three conditionals.  I'd like to replace them with a method and pass in the conditional.

Also, the conditional body is nearly repeated.  Is it possible to create a method that exist only locally within MyMethod()?  So the code below reduces to something like this:

//reduced code

```
public ClassZ MyMethod (Class1 class1Var, Class2 class2Var)
{
 return localMethod((class1Var.SomeBool && !class2Var.SomeBool), false, "This is string1");
 return localMethod((class1Var.SomeBool && !class2Var.IsMatch(class2Var)), true);
 return localMethod((class1Var.SomeProperty.HasValue && !class2Var.SomeBool), false, "This is string2");

//...localMethod() defined here...
}
```

But in the above, only one should return.

//original code

```
public ClassZ MyMethod (Class1 class1Var, Class2 class2Var)
{

 if(class1Var.SomeBool && !class2Var.SomeBool)
 {
   return new ClassZ
   {
     Property1 = false,
     String1 = "This is string1"
   };
 }

 if(class1Var.SomeBool && !class2Var.IsMatch(class2Var))
 {
   return new ClassZ
   {
     Property1 = true,
   };
 }
 if(class1Var.SomeProperty.HasValue && !class2Var.SomeBool)
 {
   return new ClassZ
   {
     Property1 = false,
     String1 = "This is string2"
   };
 }

}
```

Basically, I'd like to create a temporary method within a method.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want but surely your local method could just  be a private method?

Comment: It could.  I'd rather try to keep it inside MyMethod() since it doesn't need to exist outside.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, if you are really concerned about accidentally calling it, you could make the whole thing into a nested class, but really what is your concern? If it is private, it can't even be called by derived classes so providing it is clearly documented as not for use, what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Func` notation for this.  `Funcs` encapsulate delegate methods.  Read the documentation of `Funcs` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).  For a `Func` with `n` generic parameters, the first `n-1` are the inputs of the method and the last parameter is the return type.  Try something like this:

```
public ClassZ MyMethod (Class1 class1Var, Class2 class2Var)
{
    Func<bool, bool, string, ClassZ> myFunc 
             = (predicate, prop1Value, string1Value) => 
                      predicate 
                      ? new ClassZ { Property1 = prop1Value, String1 = string1Value }
                      : null;
    return myFunc((class1Var.SomeBool && !class2Var.SomeBool), false, "This is string1")
           ?? myFunc((class1Var.SomeBool && !class2Var.IsMatch(class2Var)), true)
           ?? myFunc((class1Var.SomeProperty.HasValue && !class2Var.SomeBool), false, "This is string2");
}
```

Here, we instantiate a `Func` that takes in a `bool` (the predicate), the parameters to set (the second `bool` and the `string`), and returns a `ClassZ`.

This is also using null coalescing (the `??` notation), which returns the first non-null argument.  Read more about null coalescing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

The other option is to use `Actions`, which encapsulate `void` methods.  Read about `Actions` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).  You could instantiate a new `ClassZ`, and then call 3 `Actions` on it, which conditionally set the variables provided.

```
public ClassZ MyMethod (Class1 class1Var, Class2 class2Var)
{
     Action<bool, bool, string, ClassZ> myAction 
         = (predicate, prop1Value, string1Value, classZInstance) => 
                  if (predicate) 
                  { 
                      classZIntance.Property1 = prop1Value; 
                      classZInstance.String1 = string1Value;
                  }
     var myClassZ = new ClassZ();
     myAction((class1Var.SomeBool && !class2Var.SomeBool), false, "This is string1", myClassZ)
     myAction((class1Var.SomeBool && !class2Var.IsMatch(class2Var)), true, classZ)
     myAction((class1Var.SomeProperty.HasValue && !class2Var.SomeBool), false, "This is string2", myClassZ);
     return myClassZ;
}
```